# ImageMagick.net Background colour of annotated text/label always black

Tags: imagemagick, magick.net, imagemagick.net

I am trying to add a label/annotation text (where the background colour of the text is transparent) to an existing image.

I have tried a couple of different approaches but I keep getting a black background colour.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Attempt 1:**

```
using (var images = new MagickImageCollection())
using (var img = new MagickImage(imgBytes))
{
    img.Resize(imageDto.Width, imageDto.Height);

    using (var imgText = new MagickImage(MagickColors.None, imageDto.Width, imageDto.Height))
    {
        var labelSettings = new MagickReadSettings()
        {
            BackgroundColor = MagickColors.None,
            Font = "Arial",
            FontPointsize = imageDto.FontSize,
            FillColor = MagickColors.Blue,
            BorderColor = MagickColors.None,
        };

        imgText.Read("label:" + imageDto.WatermarkText, labelSettings);
        img.Composite(imgText, Gravity.South);


        img.Write($"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.png");
        return img.ToBase64();

    }
}
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
using (var img = new MagickImage(imgBytes))
{
    img.Resize(imageDto.Width, imageDto.Height);

    // Load the original image and add it to the collection.
    images.Add(img);

    // Text label watermark settings
    var labelSettings = new MagickReadSettings()
    {
        BackgroundColor = new MagickColor(MagickColors.Transparent),
        Font = "Arial",
        FontPointsize = imageDto.FontSize,
        FillColor = MagickColors.Blue
    };

    // Create the label image.
    var label = new MagickImage($"label:{imageDto.WatermarkText}", labelSettings);

    // Extent the width of the label to match the width of the original image.
    label.Extent(img.Width, 0, Gravity.Center);
    label.Transparent(MagickColors.Black);

    // Add the label to the collection.
    images.Add(label);

    // Append the images to create the output image.
    using (var result = images.AppendVertically())
    {
        result.Write($"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.png");
        return result.ToBase64();
    }
}
```

Both attempts produce the same image with a black background (in the area where the text was added to the image)

[image: Black BG on added text].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is probably the easiest one. But you should use the following overload instead: `img.Composite(imgText, Gravity.South, CompositeOperator.Over);` The default is `CompositeOperator.In` and that is not what you should use to get the label as an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, you cannot draw transparency for text or background on an opaque image. So you have to draw a colored (black) rectangle, then flood fill it with transparency, then draw your colored text onto the transparent image. For example with your image:

```
convert image.png \
-draw "translate 250,250 fill black rectangle -50,-50 50,50 \
fill none matte 0,0 floodfill" \
-fill "rgba(255,0,0,1)" -pointsize 20 \
-gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TESTING" \
result.png
```

[image]

ADDITION:

If you only want the text, then leave out the background color and just write the text.

```
convert image.png \
-fill "red" -pointsize 20 \
-gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TESTING" \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: In your sample image, the annotated text has a white background. How do you make that white background transparent? That is what I am asking. Thank you

Comment: The white is from the color of the stack overflow page. It is really transparent and the white is showing through. Extract the PNG image from stack overflow and open in some viewer and you will see it is transparent

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean, but what I wanted was the light grey of the base image to be visible (not the white of SO), Just to re-iterate, I have many images that I want to apply some text to, I only want the text to be put on and keep the base layer. Hope I explained that right.

Comment: See my ADDITION above in my answer.